# How to determine the authority of a deployed contract?

Tags: contract-development

I'm new to Ethereum and just read all the doc about it. From my understanding, if a contract is open source, anyone can clone the code from Github and deployed it unlimit times.

However, take Uniswap as example, at [etherscan gas tracker](https://etherscan.io/gastracker), they list [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d) as the *authenticated* deployed instance.

My question is how we or the community or even etherscan determine which deployed instance is the one we should use?

The first one? traffic? etc.?

Comment: Well uniswap has a frontend, its connected to a set of contracts, these are the official uniswap contracts, their addresses are marked in their documentation, as simple as that.

Comment: @Foxxxey thanks for the answer. That makes sense to me!